# Add regex to ignore /js /img and /css

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, url

I have this regular expression

```
// Look for /en/ or /en-US/ or /en_US/ on the URL
    var matches = req.url.match( /^\/([a-zA-Z]{2,3}([-_][a-zA-Z]{2})?)(\/|$)/ );
```

Now with the above regular express it will cause the problem with the URL such as:

http://mydomain.com/`css`/bootstrap.css

or

http://mydomain.com/`js`/jquery.js

because my regular expression is to strip off 2-3 characters from A-Z or a-z

My question is how would I add in to this regular expression to not strip off anything with

`js` or `img` or `css` or `ext`

Without impacting the original one.

I'm not so expert on regular expression :(

Comment: which language/tool are you using?

Comment: I'm using Javascript/node.js @Anirudh

Comment: If you write the right regex, strings like img, css and ext should not be catched

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa yeah and that is why I need some help to add these three condition to my regex

Comment: @Ali Why are you not using the built in URL parser? http://nodejs.org/api/url.html

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum because am not Ali..:) :P

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum is there an easier way?

Comment: @Ali http://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost

Comment: @Ali. What I meant is that you DON'T need a special condition (apart from js)  at all since all your wanted strings have 2 chars, and optionally a hyphen and other 2 chars. img, ext and css are of 3 chars so they will never be catched

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa at first I thought it wouldn't catch that, but it seems like the condition caught anything with 2 characters and three characters already :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative lookahead?

```
var matches = req.url.match(/^\/(?!(js|css))([a-zA-Z]{2,3}([-_][a-zA-Z]{2})?)(\/|$)/ );
```

`\` *not* followed by `js` or `css`

Comment: I'm getting this error for some reason

500 TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined

Comment: Note that if you're using result of the match - numbers have shifted a bit, since I've added extra "()"

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have not defined what exactly you are searching for.
Define an array with lowercased common language codes ([Common language codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_code))
This way you'll know what to look for.

After that, convert your url to lowercase and replace all '_' with '-' and search for every member of the array in the resulting string using indexOf().

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you're using the regex to replace text, I changed it to a replace function.  Also, you forced the regex to match the start of the string; I don't see how it would match anything with that.  Anyway, here's my approach:

```
var result = req.url.replace(/\/([a-z]{2,3}([-_][a-z]{2})?)(?=\/|$)/i,
  function(s,t){
    switch(t){case"js":case"img":case"css":case"ext":return s;}
    return "";
  }
);
```